# Ionic4: PDF upload to server

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to upload PDF file to server using form-group how i do it or any possible way to do it same. I'll try file chooser plugin but that was not supported in ios

Comment: have a look on [file-transfer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/) plugin of ionic

Comment: but to pick file first because file chooser plugin not work in ios

Answer (score 2):

you can use file chooser plugin conditionally

check platform using : https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform

```js
if(this.platform.is('ios')){
    // run ios code
}
else{
    // run android code
}
```

For ios :  https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-picker

For android :  https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser

Then use file transfer plugin to upload : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer